# Integration test fails when it hits db context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, playwright

When I open the web page, it hits the controller, which calls the DBContext, which returns a single object populated from the database.
But when I do the same thing from the playwright integration test, it follows the same path and crashes when it tries to retrieve anything from the database.
It doesn't appear to be getting an exception. It just goes away.
I've removed all other tables from the context.
I've tried different tables.
I've tried different contexts.
The common thread is that wherever it hits the database first, crashes.
But only when run from the test.
The page still works fine if I run it directly.

If the test gets an instance of the context, it can interact with the database just fine. It can read and set values as expected.

The SUT fails when I call either of

```
 string? conn = Database.GetConnectionString();
 bool connected = this.Database.CanConnect();
```

And again, the same code works correctly when NOT called from the test.
Further, it acts a bit like a memory error where the failure point jumps around a bit. But that seems unlikely in C#.
The test looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void ScanTitleTestRunner() {
        Run(ScanTitleTest);
    }

    protected void Run(Func<IPage, Task> method) {
        Task task = Browser.WithPageAsync(method);
        task.Wait(45000); // it doesn't wait. Returns properly.
    }

    public async Task ScanTitleTest(IPage page) {
        // Arrange
        await page.GotoAsync(Fixture.ServerAddress + "Scan");
        await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync(LoadState.DOMContentLoaded);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Scan QR - Frontend", await page.TitleAsync());
    }
```

When loaded, the page calls the controller, which calls this, which in the actual app, returns the value 1.

```
    public int? GetInt() {
        return QRKeys.Select(x => 1).FirstOrDefault(); // app exits immediately. No exception.
    }
```

If I disable JustMyCode, it gets further than I would have expected, then fails when it actually accesses the database.

If I hit F10 on GetInt, then I get this in the debug window:

```
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (0x1510) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: What do you see in the Debug Output window? Abnormal program terminations (i.e. crashes) should always be listed. Additionally, do you have the "Just My Code" enabled or disabled? Is it your ASP.NET process that crashes or is it Chrome? Are you using the correct Chrome automation binaries? (I'm not too familiar with Playwright, but WebDriver binaries for Chrome are version-specific and need to be updated almost every week it seems)

Comment: @Dai  Answers above. Seems unlikely to be the drivers. Chrome continues on happily. All it knows is that the AJAX call never returns.

Comment: Your `protected void Run` is wrong. You need to be using `async` properly.

Comment: It wasn't crashing after all. It was locking up because the database thread pool was exhausted. Resolved by reducing the number of threads used by having a single que and single background worker instead of each one having a dedicated que and worker.